# How to sort Wordpress "links" and "categories" random

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

A new client wants us to maintain his old website made by someone else. I currently have this code that I somehow can't get to work. I want to make the output of the code show random. Instead of an alphabetical order. I've tried 'orderby' => 'rand'. But without luck.

```
<?php
      $bookmarks = get_bookmarks();
      if ($bookmarks != '') { ?>
         <?php foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) { ?>
         <a onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Partners outgoing', '
<?php echo $bookmark->link_name; ?>');return true;" title="<?php echo $bookmark->link_name; ?>" href="<?php echo clean_url($bookmark->link_url); ?>" target="_blank" class="Allemaal grid3 partners 

<?php /* start van class --- hier de categorie oproepen en zonder spatie plaatsen*/
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $bookmark->link_id, 'link_category', array( 'fields' => 'all' )  );
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
$getterm2 = $term_single->name;
$getterm3 = str_replace(' ', '', $getterm2);
echo ' ';
echo $getterm3;
}
/* einde van class ---hier de categorie oproepen en zonder spatie plaatsen*/
?>">

<img src="<?php echo $bookmark->link_image ?>">
<p><?php echo $bookmark->link_name; ?></p>
</a>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

To see this in action you can go [here](https://www.klimaatplein.com/partners-van-klimaatplein)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `shuffle($term_list)` before the foreach loop.

Comment: I tried this, but that didn’t work. Instead I’ve used shuffle($bookmarks); Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I was not sure which array you want to shuffle, did it work with shuffling the $bookmarks array?